# Creting FOREIGN KEY constraint on multiple columns with one of them being constant value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, constraints

When I have table with PRIMARY KEY from 2 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE SizeTypes 
(
    TypeID          tinyint NOT NULL,
    SizeID          tinyint NOT NULL,
    Name            varchar(100) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_SizeType 
        PRIMARY KEY (TypeID, SizeID)
)
```

How can I create second table with a foreign key that have 1st constant value and 2nd from column like below:

```
CREATE TABLE Something 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    SizeTypeID_1 TINYINT,
    SizeTypeID_2 TINYINT,
    SizeTypeID_3 TINYINT,

    CONSTRAINT FK_Something_SizeTypes_1 
        FOREIGN KEY (1, SizeTypeID_1)
        REFERENCES SizeTypes(TypeID, SizeID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Something_SizeTypes_2 
        FOREIGN KEY (2, SizeTypeID_2)
        REFERENCES SizeTypes(TypeID, SizeID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Something_SizeTypes_3 
        FOREIGN KEY (3, SizeTypeID_3)
        REFERENCES SizeTypes(TypeID, SizeID)
)
```

This can be done using `FOREIGN KEY`, if yes then how?

If no then what other ways to do this I have? Triggers on INSERT and UPDATE for table something and on DELETE for table SizeTypes? Any other choices I have?

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What, pray tell, are you trying to accomplish? Is it something that three foreign key references without constants would not do?

Comment: I want for example: SizeTypeID_1 values to be from 1 to 7, SizeTypeID_2 values 1 to 3 and SizeTypeID_3 values 1 to 5. Those values can change depending on values in table SizeTypes.
If this is possible I want table SizeTypes to be one and not 3 different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the following code will let you create suitable check constraints with the check implemented by a separate function:

```
-- Create the first table.
create table SizeTypes(
  TypeId TinyInt not NULL,
  SizeId TinyInt not NULL,
  Name VarChar(100) not NULL,
  constraint PK_SizeType primary key ( TypeId, SizeId ) );
go

-- Create a function to implement the logic for the check constraint.
create function CheckSizeTypeId(
  @TypeId TinyInt, @SizeId TinyInt )
  returns Int
  as begin
  -- Replace the following statement with the logic for your check.
  if @SizeId >= 0 and @SizeId <= ( select SizeId from SizeTypes where TypeID = @TypeID )
    return 1;
  return 0;    
  end;
go

-- Create the second table with the check constraints.
create table Something(
  Id Int identity(1,1) primary key,
  SizeTypeId_1 TinyInt,
  SizeTypeId_2 TinyInt,
  SizeTypeId_3 TinyInt,
  constraint Check_SizeTypeId_1 check ( dbo.CheckSizeTypeId( 1, SizeTypeId_1 ) = 1 ),
  constraint Check_SizeTypeId_2 check ( dbo.CheckSizeTypeId( 2, SizeTypeId_2 ) = 1 ),
  constraint Check_SizeTypeId_3 check ( dbo.CheckSizeTypeId( 3, SizeTypeId_3 ) = 1 ) );
go

-- Houseclean.
drop table SizeTypes;
drop table Something;
drop function CheckSizeTypeId;
```

Note that the constraints restrict what you can do with values in `Something`. Changes in `SizeTypes` will not revalidate data in `Something`, though that could be implemented in a trigger on `SizeTypes`.

Comment: Something exacly like that I needed. I'll only change statement to 
"if ( select 1 from SizeTypes where SizeID = @ SizeId and TypeID = @ TypeID )" and create trigger on SizeTypes as you said. Thank you.